# What is the difference between x_axis and line_axis of boxlayout in java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, boxlayout

Both x_axis and line_axis arranges components from left to right. Then what's the difference between them?

This question is from Java Swing boxlayout layout manager.

Comment: Never used `BoxLayout`, though AFAIU, the former (LINE_AXIS), can be changed depending on the `Component's Orientation`, if you change the Orientation of the Component to Right to Left, this will change too, though the latter will always add components from `Left to Right`, no metter what...

Answer (score 6):

From the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html):

> **X_AXIS** - Components are laid out horizontally from left to right.
>
> **LINE_AXIS** - Components are laid out the way words are laid out in a
> line, based on the container's ComponentOrientation property. If the
> container's ComponentOrientation is horizontal then components are
> laid out horizontally, otherwise they are laid out vertically. For
> horizontal orientations, if the container's ComponentOrientation is
> left to right then components are laid out left to right, otherwise
> they are laid out right to left. For vertical orientations components
> are always laid out from top to bottom.

Answer (score 4):

I hope the following code example, might be able to provide more insight into what the Java Docs has to say on BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS :

---

> LINE_AXIS - Components are laid out the way words are laid out in a
>   line, based on the container's ComponentOrientation property. If the
>   container's ComponentOrientation is horizontal then components are
>   laid out horizontally, otherwise they are laid out vertically. For
>   horizontal orientations, if the  container's ComponentOrientation is
>   left to right then components are laid out  left to right, otherwise
>   they are laid out right to left. For vertical  orientations components
>   are always laid out from top to bottom.

---

> X_AXIS - Components are laid out horizontally from left to right.

---

Do watch the **last two rows**, how `Buttons` are added to the second last `JPanel` from **RIGHT tO LEFT** and from __LEFT to RIGHT_ to the last `JPanel`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoxLayoutExample
{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel middlePanel;
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private JPanel addedBottomPanel;
    private JButton[] button;

    public BoxLayoutExample()
    {
        button = new JButton[12];
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Box Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 5, 5));

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(
                            topPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            topPanel.add(button[i]);
        }

        middlePanel = new JPanel();
        middlePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(
                            middlePanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            middlePanel.add(button[i]);
        }

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();     
        bottomPanel.setComponentOrientation(
                        ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);        
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(
                            bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            bottomPanel.add(button[i]);
        }

        addedBottomPanel = new JPanel();        
        addedBottomPanel.setComponentOrientation(
                        ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);        
        addedBottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(
                            addedBottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        for (int i = 9; i < 12; i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            addedBottomPanel.add(button[i]);
        }

        contentPane.add(topPanel);
        contentPane.add(middlePanel);
        contentPane.add(bottomPanel);
        contentPane.add(addedBottomPanel);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new BoxLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: BoxLayoutExample]

Answer (score 2):

**X_AXIS** is always horizontal.  **LINE_AXIS** can be both based on the container's **ComponentOrientation** property.

Source:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html